# How do you use a class attribute on a class instance method decorator?

Tags: python

I have some classes that look something like this:

```
class Foo:
    bar = None

    @baz(frob=bar)
    def oof():
        pass

class Rab(Foo):
    bar = 'zab'
```

I don't have control over the `@baz` decorator and I need to to use the class attribute `bar` of the new class `Rab`. But calling `Rab.oof()` uses the `bar=None` of the base class.

Comment: The issue is that `@baz(frob=bar)` is evaluated at the definition of `Foo`, and not re-evalutaed on the subclassing. Can you overload `oof` in `Rab`?

Answer (score 5):

So here is a kind of weird/interesting approach where you only need to modify `Foo`, the idea here is that a new decorator is created that delays the `baz` decoration until the function is first called with some caching based on the class name so that it only happens once.

Note that this also includes a dummy implementation for `baz` which just prints the `frob` argument that was provided, but this approach should work fine without needing to modify `baz`:

```
def baz(frob):
    def deco(func):
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            print('frob:', frob)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return deco

def newdeco(func):
    def wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(wrapped, 'cache'):
            wrapped.cache = {}
        cls = self.__class__.__name__
        if cls not in wrapped.cache:
            wrapped.cache[cls] = baz(frob=getattr(self.__class__, 'bar'))(func)
        wrapped.cache[cls](self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped

class Foo:
    bar = None

    @newdeco
    def oof(self):
        pass

class Rab(Foo):
    bar = 'zab'


f = Foo()
f.oof()

r = Rab()
r.oof()
```

I also had to add a `self` argument to `oof` based on the assumption that `oof` is a method, if `baz` is also converting the function to a staticmethod I'm not sure this approach will work.

Comment: This is pretty neat. You might want to make `wrapped.cache` a `WeakKeyDictionary`, and cache by class object instead of just the name (names may clash).

Comment: Very nice.  This is almost certainly the best idea on this question yet.  :)

Comment: This is a great answer, I am intending to utilize this on a Pyramid app using a Cornice resource `@view` decorator. I'm not sure if it'll work for that because the view gets registered in Pyramid's config when the app starts up but I'll try it and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: If it doesn't end up working it just occurred to me that you might be able to do something clever with a metaclass on `Foo` to apply the decorator.

Answer (score 3):

You *could* unwrap the closure from `Foo` and pull out the wrapped function, then re-wrap it in the decorator in the derived class.  But if there's any way you can get at `Foo` or even `baz` to change their implementation, it'd be better.

```
class Rab(Foo):
    bar = 'zab'
    oof = baz(frob=bar)(Foo.oof.func_closure[0].cell_contents)
```

Comment: Hmm, that would definitely work but I'd prefer to not do it that way. I do have control over `Foo`. How would you change that implementation to be better?

Answer (score 2):

You can keep the undecorated version of `oof`, let's call it `_oof_raw`, and re-wrap it in your subclass definition. In order to keep the undecorated version, you need to decorate "manually", i.e. not using the `@` syntactic sugar.

```
class Foo:
    bar = None

    def _oof_raw(self):
        pass

    oof = baz(frob=bar)(_oof_raw)

class Rab(Foo):
    bar = 'zab'

    oof = baz(frob=bar)(Foo._oof_raw)
```

Comment: You could even mix this with a metaclass to do the wrapping in the metaclass `__new__`, rather than explicitly in each subclass.  That would still be limited though, as it wouldn't be able to respond to changes to `Rab.bar` at runtime without some pretty significant noodling around with the accessor to the class variable.

Comment: @SilasRay, yes, i agree that if this has to be applied to many subclasses, using a meta-class might be a good approach. (but if not, my personal preference would be to avoid unnecessary magic)